# Deep Learning models train really slow Jetson Nano

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I recently bought a Jetson Nano and I'm amazed with everything about it. But I don't know what is happening, because I created a very simple neural network with keras and it's taking way to long. I know is taking to long, because I runned the same ANN in my PC's CPU and it was faster than the jetson nano.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))

classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
```

I should mention that of course, I did the correct installation of TensorFlow GPU library and not the normal TensorFlow, in fact I used the resources in this link: [TensorFlow GPU Jetson Nano](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048776/jetson-nano/official-tensorflow-for-jetson-nano-/)

Answer (score 3):

Jetson Nano is mainly for inferencing. Training is not preferred even though its possible.
This [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1050620/jetson-nano/can-i-use-jetson-nano-to-train-a-neural-network-/) might help.
You can try using Nvidia's Transfer Learning Toolkit and Deepstream for ideal and efficient use on Nano.

Answer (score 0):

@Juan Carlos Jchr

Hey, just check https://stackexchange.com/sites

I think that your question will get better answes here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/